# linq to entities POCO creation

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-entities, poco

Working on a wcf webhttp service that processes data using linq to entities and mysql as the db.

My db has one table - employee which has fields EmployeeID, FirstName,LastName, phone, city, country, 
I added the db as a entity data model. I created another class called EmployeeEntity

Code was as follows (before I started reading up on DTO, POCO etc)

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Model")]    
public class EmployeeEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public long empID{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string firstName{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string firstName{ get; set; }
}
```

To get a list of employees I use

`var employeeList = from employee in bd.employees
                             select new VendorEntity
                             {
                                 empID = employee.EmployeeID
                                 firstName = employee.FirstName,
                                 lastName = employee.LastName

                             };`

The client solution has a copy of the class EmployeeEntity

It uses Microsoft.Http and creates the data contract thus -

```
HttpContent content = 
HttpContentExtensions.CreateDataContract<EmployeeEntity>(empEntity);
```

Is the EmployeeEntity (that I created manually) a POCO class. To me it seems to be so since my service now passes/consumes light xml.

Am I falling into the anemic domain anti-pattern? Or am I doing the right thing and not taking advantage of any automation that might exist to create the classes.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anemic domain pattern implies crucial domain logic is not in domain classes.  Since you have posted no logic its impossible to say how anemic your domain is.

You're probably doing the right thing.

Comment: Currently most of the processing/logic is in my webservice where I read from the db, process the recordsthen, populate EmployeeEntity (which may contain less fields than the original entity class) and then pass it to the clients.